# Why do these pointer functions have different outputs

Tags: c

These codes look functionally the same but they have different outputs;

```
#include <stdio.h>

void change_ptr(const char *a){
  const char **b = &a;
  *b = "bad";
}

int main(){
  const char *a = "good";
  change_ptr(a);
  printf("%s",a);
  return 0;
}
```

outputs good

```
#include <stdio.h>

void change_ptr(const char **a){
  *a = "bad";
}

int main(){
  const char *a = "good";
  change_ptr(&a);
  printf("%s",a);
  return 0;
}
```

outputs bad

Since they are both calling a pointer to a pointer, referencing the pointer and altering it, they should be functionally the same, but they aren't.

Comment: Parameters, even pointers, are passed by value. The pointer in the first example is a copy of the pointer declared in `main`. You can change what the copy points to but you can't change what the original points to from inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

Per [C 2017 6.5.2.2](https://files.lhmouse.com/standards/ISO%20C%20N2176.pdf):

> In preparing for the call to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument.95)

> 95. A function may change the values of its parameters, but these changes cannot affect the values of the arguments. On the
>     other hand, it is possible to pass a pointer to an object, and the function may change the value of the object pointed to.

Aka "call by value".  This is typically implemented by pushing the evaluated arguments onto to the stack.

In first example we push the value of the variable `main:a` and crucially this means means that `main:a != change_ptr:*(&a)` as `change_ptr:a` is different variable.  The life time of `change_ptr:a`ends when the function returns which is why no changes to it will be externally visible.

In the 2nd example we are pushing the address of `&a` and now `main:a == change_ptr:*a`.

Answer (score 1):

The first code is using the address of "a" (&a) which is an argument on the stack or a stack address, while the second code is correct.